# How to use Let's Encrypt for my private server while ISP blocked port 80 and 443?

Tags: ssl, https, server, lets-encrypt

I am setting up a WebDAV server behind traefik using docker compose. Also,I want to add HTTPS support to it, so that keeping my data private. I bought a domain name and prefer to use Let's Encrypt, because it's free of charge.
But as far as I know, Let's Encrypt requires TLS, HTTP or DNS challenge. While last option seems only for big companies who owns the public DNS server, other two options need port 80 or 443. The problem is that these 2 port are all blocked by the ISP. So is there any workaround? How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While last option seems only for big companies who owns the public DNS server

If you own the domain, you should have full control over the DNS records — free of charge, by going to the vendor you bought the domain from, and finding the section for the DNS controls. If you have your domain pointing your IP address, you've already used it, probably by adding an `A` or `AAAA` record. Let's Encrypt DNS challenge requires only a `TXT` record, which should be available on virtually every domain registrar's DNS controls.

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to change or add and remove TXT record often? If not how can it be safe?

Comment: @Slimpothive It poses no risk to keep the TXT record up there. Though you have to do the method again each time the Let's Encrypt certificate expires.